# How come when i took the integral of the function of a circle, i didn´t get the equation of a circle.

Tags: calculus, integration, geometry, area

okay so this is what i was able to figure out
$$x^2+y^2=r^2$$
$$y=±√(r^2-x^2 )$$
therefore the área would be 
$$\int_0^r √(r^2-x^2 )dx $$
after solving it i ended up getting 
$$ r^2/2∙ ([arcsin⁡(x/r)+sin2(2arcsin(x/r))/2]_0^r )$$ 
hence
$$=(pi)r^2/4$$
and thus i came to that but i dont understand what is incorrect (i didnt make any mistakes when integrating the fuction), but that equation is not the área of a cirle which should be $4r(pi)^2$
can someone please explain this? and why it is incorect

Comment: The area of a circle is $\pi r^2$, not $4r {\pi}^2$.

Comment: Your integral formula is integrating only a quarter circle; the sector of the circle in the first quadrant

Comment: That's the area of a quarter circle - the quarter with $x,y\geq 0$.

Answer (score 3):

As you have pointed out $y$ has two roots. One positive ad the other negative. You've considered only the positive one for the integration.

Also your limits go from $0$ to $r$, which is again anly from the midpoint to the circumference of the circle.

So, on the whole you are considering only quarter of the circle i.e the part that is present in the first quadrant for integration. Hence you are getting $1/4^{th}$ of the answer that you should've got.